# Integrate MemorizingTrustManager library in Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I'm stuck trying to add https://github.com/ge0rg/MemorizingTrustManager to my Android Studio project (which consists of one MainActivity only at the moment). I tried the steps in the readme and did some Google research but no success. I just can't manage to integrate this package as library. Maybe someone has already succeeded doing so and can help me out.

Whenever I try to add this as library, its add only example module(example is the name of module in the library) but I want to add whole project in studio project.

**EDIT**

[Project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUsne.png)

[Download Demo Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZSHL.png)

Comment: may i know what is the issue while integrating , i did it successfully

Comment: it only integrate its module named 'example', but in library there is another src folder, gradel & .iml file outside 'example' module. I want to integrate library as "MemorizingTrustManage", not as "example". I see a project "Converstion" at github & this project use this library.

Comment: download the project and then add ':MemorizingTrustManager-master' in project settings.gradle.After that "open Module Setting", at their click on Dependencies Tab. Click on + button and then include module as MemorizingTrustManager-master in module dependency.

Comment: @ManishJain yeah.. thnx buddy... it added in gradle but now gradle sync is failed.. the error is `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

Comment: where you put the MemorizingTrustManage library in the project?

Comment: import module from project name... sibling of app module (default module)..

Comment: @ManishJain it shows example module but in dependency tab it show both.. example & MemorizingTrustManager. I already add both as module dependency. but gradle error found.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've put a folder of sources in the libs directory. It would be better to included those sources as their own module just as you have done with the emoji library.

1. Click an existing module
2. Press F4
3. Click the Green Plus add-module button in the top left.
4. Select Import Gradle Project
5. Select the MemorizingTrustManager sources directory

Double check that Android Studio has added dependencies for you, otherwise look in settings.gradle and add the module name (eg. `include :memorizingTrustManager`), then in your main module, add the same module to dependencies:

```
compile project(':memorizingTrustManager')
```

Finally check the gradle file of the imported MemorizingTrustManager module and ensure it has

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

instead of

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

and that it does not contain an `applicationId`

Comment: it added just like `include :example` and `compile project(':example')` and that irritate me.. many times it throw gradle error like `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`.

Comment: I think this is a bit of an XY problem - you are comitted to a solution which is messy rather than fixing those gradle problems you mentioned. Post the gradle errors you are getting into your question, along with the gradle files you've created